# Merging two queries into One

Tags: mysql

Here's my code:

```
$queryresult="SELECT a.ArticleID, a.Title, a.Publication, l.EnglishLanguage, m.EnglishMedia, a.PublicationYear, a.Size , REPLACE( GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT REPLACE( c.EnglishCategory, ',',  '' ) ) ,  '/',  ',' ) ,  GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT au.EnglishName,  '/' ), GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT au.PictureURL ) , a.Abstract,a.URL,m.IconURL,REPLACE( GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT REPLACE( au.EnglishName,  ',',  '' ) ) ,  '/',  ',' )
FROM article a
LEFT JOIN aritcletocategory ac ON a.ArticleID = ac.ArticleID
LEFT JOIN category c ON ac.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
LEFT JOIN articletoauthor at ON a.ArticleID = at.ArticleID
JOIN MediaType m ON a.MediaTypeID = m.MediaTypeID
JOIN Language l ON a.LanguageID = l.LanguageID
LEFT JOIN author au ON at.AuthorID = au.AuthorID
WHERE a.Title REGEXP '".$search."' || replace(au.EnglishName,',','') REGEXP '".$search."' || replace(au.HebrewName,',','') REGEXP '".$search."' || a.Keywords REGEXP '".$search."'|| c.EnglishCategory REGEXP '".$search."' || a.Abstract REGEXP '".$search."'|| a.Publication REGEXP '".$search."'GROUP BY a.ArticleID";
$finalresult=show_result($queryresult);
```

And the Id I got from result of this query is used in the following query:

```
foreach($finalresult as $ress){
$queryresults="SELECT a.ArticleID, a.Title, a.Publication, l.EnglishLanguage, m.EnglishMedia, a.PublicationYear, a.Size , REPLACE( GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT REPLACE( c.EnglishCategory,  ',',  '' ) ) ,  '/',  ',' ) , GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT au.EnglishName ,  '/' ), GROUP_CONCAT( au.PictureURL ) , a.Abstract,a.URL, REPLACE( GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT REPLACE( au.HebrewName,  ',',  '' ) ) ,  '/',  ',' ),m.IconURL,REPLACE( GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT REPLACE( au.EnglishName,  ',',  '' ) ) ,  '/',  ',' )
FROM article a
LEFT JOIN aritcletocategory ac ON a.ArticleID = ac.ArticleID
LEFT JOIN category c ON ac.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
LEFT JOIN articletoauthor at ON a.ArticleID = at.ArticleID
LEFT JOIN author au ON at.AuthorID = au.AuthorID
JOIN MediaType m ON a.MediaTypeID = m.MediaTypeID
JOIN Language l ON a.LanguageID = l.LanguageID
WHERE a.ArticleID =".$ress[0]." GROUP BY a.ArticleID ";
$finalresults=show_result($queryresults);
```

I wish to get the result with one query rather than using two queries. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you  tried union?

Comment: You can use or in the where statement.

Answer (score 1):

As your queries have the same structure you can use `UNION`

```
--Query 1
SELECT ...

UNION

--Query 2
SELECT ...

;
```

Check out [w3schools - SQL UNION Operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) for more information.

Or if you want to get more professional information: [MySQL Manual: Union Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/union.html)

Comment: Please don't línk to w3schools (also known as "w3fools"). That site is full of errors. A link to the MySQL manual would be much better.